# Amazon EC2 And Web API

Tags: amazon-ec2

Folks, I am new to Amazon AWS and currently using the free tier for the 12 months, has anyone got stung with bad bills through that period.

Also if you took a basic asp.net API and a windows EC2 t2 micro which I selected from the free tier eligibility.

How much would that device cost outside it's very confusing to work it out? I have already set up a SQL server express box just created a bucket but now also trying to figure out how to restore the file.

Say the api was only getting a few hits from me a month and was able to keep the machine on 24x7 are you charged for idel time I the machine on but not sending out data.

Comment: Some links which might help: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/monitor_estimated_charges_with_cloudwatch.html, https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/, https://calculator.aws/#/

Comment: Also look into https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/

Answer (score 0):

Cost management is a very important part of using AWS; there are plenty of users who have been stung by unexpected usage charges.

To help manage your usage charges, AWS provides a number of resources including a cost estimator so you can estimate monthly usage costs, which you can find here:
https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html

In addition to this, you can also setup billing alarms to notify you of when your estimated usage charges exceeds specific thresholds. You can read how to do that here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/monitor_estimated_charges_with_cloudwatch.html